# How to use Replace function in VBScript

Tags: replace, vbscript

I don't know why this code doesn't work:

```
Dim a
a = InputBox("What time do you want?")
If InStr(a, "pm") Then
  (Replace(a, "pm", ""))
  a = a + 12
  c = MsgBox(a, 0, Time)
  WScript.Quit
Else
End If
b = MsgBox(a & form, 0, "L")
```

Whenever I try to start it, it responds with:

> "Error: Expected Statement"

Is it because the `Replace` statement isn't right or because there's a mistake in the rest of the script?

Comment: Yes, why don't you [look up how to use `Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954(v=vs.84).aspx) or any VBScript function for that matter, why come here and ask?

Comment: To fix the error fix line 4 - `a = Replace(a, "pm","")` which is the cause of the error. `Replace()` has to return something, `(Replace(a, "pm",""))` is not a valid statement without a return value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you try to run that code you should get the following error

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected statement
>   Line 4

which will lead you to the culprit which is

```
(Replace(a, "pm",""))
```

which isn't a valid statement in VBScript hence the error.

Based on what you are trying to do the script needs to return the result of the `Replace()` function call, something like this

```
a = Replace(a, "pm","")
```